# Python logging in several modules outputs twice

Tags: python, logging

I'm not very familiar with python logging and I am trying to get it to log output to the console. I've gotten it to work but it seems that the output is seen twice in the console and I'm not sure why. I've looked at the other questions asked here about similar situations but I could not find anything that helped me.

I have three modules, lets call them **ma**, **mb**, **mc** and a **main**. The main imports these 3 modules and calls their functions.

In each module I set up a logger like so:

## ma.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test.ma') #test.mb for mb.py/test.mc for mc.py
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_log = logging.StreamHandler()
console_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
console_log.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_log)
...
...
#right before the end of each module, after I'm finished logging what I need.
logger.removeHandler(console_log)
```

## mb.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test.mb')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_log = logging.StreamHandler()
console_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
console_log.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_log)
...
...
#end of file
logger.removeHandler(console_log)
```

## mc.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('test.mc')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_log = logging.StreamHandler()
console_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
console_log.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_log)
...
...
#end of file
logger.removeHandler(console_log)
```

The main problem I'm having is that output is printing twice and for some parts of the program it is not formatted. Any help would appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better approach to using a global logger is to use a function that wraps the call to `logging.getLogger`:

```
import logging

def get_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if not logger.handlers:
        # Prevent logging from propagating to the root logger
        logger.propagate = 0
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        logger.addHandler(console)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
    return logger

def main():
    logger = get_logger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.info("This is an info message")
    logger.error("This is an error message")
    logger.debug("This is a debug message")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
2017-03-09 12:02:41,083 - __main__ - This is an info message
2017-03-09 12:02:41,083 - __main__ - This is an error message
2017-03-09 12:02:41,083 - __main__ - This is a debug message
```

**Note:** Using a function also allows us to set `logger.propagate` to `False` to prevent log messages from being sent to the root logger. This is almost certainly the cause of the duplicated output you are seeing.

**Update:** After calling `get_logger`, the desired level must be set by calling `logger.setLevel`. If this is not done, then only error messages will be seen.

Comment: I have a module with helper functions that all 3 modules which need logging call. So I added this function to that module (I added some of the formatter/setLevel changes that I have above as well). Now in each module I just call `logger = helper.get_logger('test')`. Now when I run my program, no logs show up at all, only print statements

Comment: You have to call `logger.setLevel` to set the level to `logging.DEBUG`. Otherwise, you will only see error messages. I have updated my code to make it a complete example.

Comment: I added the `logger.setLevel` function in the method in the helper module and it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To log in multiple modules, to one global file, create a logging instance and then get that instance in whichever modules you like.  So for example in main, i would have:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('Global Log')
```

Then, in every module that I want to be able to append to this log, I have:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('Global Log')
```

Now everytime you access the logger in your module, you are accessing the same logging instance.  This way, you should only have to set up and format the logger once.

More about logging instance in the docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger

Comment: I tried and it seemed to work but after I took a closer look, there's still some parts that output twice. The first time is just the general format that I have with the time/name/message, the second time it outputs it just says
DEBUG: message

Comment: According to the docs (short way down from where my link takes you) it says that using the module level functions can lead to handlers being added multiple times to the logger.  This is an issue for Python 2.7-3.2.  I'm not sure what the solution is here, i'm working on 3.4.2 and have not had this problem(i know that doesn't help much!)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was seeing logging twice due to the way `/dev/log` redirects records to the `rsyslog` daemon I have locally running.

Using a

```
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/run/systemd/journal/syslog')
```

solved my problem of double logging.